# Why does style in <ul> only affect the first <li>?

Tags: html, css

I have a `unordered list` in my code which looks a little like this

```css
.tntext {
  display: inline-block;
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  text-align: center;
  height: 40px;
  line-height: 40px;
  font-size: 20px;
  width: 150px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<ul class="tntext">
  <li>hi</li>
  <li>hi</li>
  <li>hi</li>
  <li>hi</li>
</ul>
```

This produces a list which looks like the picture below. You can see the code at this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Vusa360/5Lxzwdd9/)

[image]

However when the html is changed to something which looks like this

```css
.tntext {
  display: inline-block;
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  text-align: center;
  height: 40px;
  line-height: 40px;
  font-size: 20px;
  width: 150px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="tntext">hi</li>
  <li class="tntext">hi</li>
  <li class="tntext">hi</li>
  <li class="tntext">hi</li>
</ul>
```

This produces a list which looks like the picture below. You can see the code at this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Vusa360/5Lxzwdd9/1/)

[image]

Why does declaring the class in the `<ul>` tag only affect the first `<li>` child inside the `<ul>` tag?

Comment: I edited my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38062137/483779) with more details, hope it helps and feel free to comment.

Comment: @Pangloss Thanky you for the extra information

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's actually not "technically" affecting the `<li>` tags underneath it, but actually the first `<li>` and the `<ul>` are overlapping. The reason for this is because you are not defining the style for each of the `<li>` tags and so they are forced to inherit styles from their parent, the `.tntext` class. They inherit the width and the height, hence why the first `<li>` is overlapping with the `<ul>` tag; they both have the same height/width. Check these pictures out to see what I mean

[image][image]

If you remove the height css value from the `<ul>` tag, you will see the entire list turn red (Like so: https://jsfiddle.net/ntvcsese/ ). If you want to apply every style from that class to each `<li>` tag instead, you have to change `.tntext` to `.tntext li` in your css. Like so: https://jsfiddle.net/fhxqLboL/1/

Answer (score 3):

It looks like affecting the first `<li>`, but it does not, it is only the visual effects.

The `height: 40px;` + `line-height: 40px;` technique is commonly used for vertically aligning text to the center. If you change the value or comment out one of them, e.g. `height: 60px`, you will see it clearly that the style has nothing to do with the first `<li>` - [example](https://jsfiddle.net/b52wgyuj/).

In addition for CSS [inheritance](https://www.w3.org/wiki/Inheritance_and_cascade): Not all CSS properties are inherited, for instance `margin`, `padding`, `height`, `background-color` etc. are not inherited by default. But properties like `font-size`, `line-height`, `text-align` etc. are inherited.

Answer (score 1):

Your css should look like this, changing each list item inside of the list with calss tntext

```
    .tntext li{
  display: inline-block;
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0; 
  text-align: center;
  height: 40px;
  line-height: 40px;
  font-size: 20px;
  width: 150px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The height attribute in the css is what is making it do that.  The ul is only coloring the background for 40px because of the css.  Removing that line in the css will make all of li red as well.

Answer (score 1):

Its not affecting the first `<li>`, actually you are targeting the `<ul>` in the first case and you have set its `height` equal to `40px` which is equal to the `<li>` so the `<ul>` is equal in `height` to the first `<li>` and you are seeing as the first `<li>` is getting the `background-color: red`.
You can get it more clear if you set the first `<li>` `background-color` to something different and change the `height` of `<ul>` to something between `40px` to `80px`.